# preg_match with two choices

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have to make a regex for two choices, for exemple I have a string:

```
apps; chrome
```

I have to split the string in 2 pieces without spaces

1-> apps
2-> chrome

but the problem is that string might be "apps;chrome" (w/o space after ;)

I tried with explode

```
$part = explode(";", $search);
```

If the string is with space between characters the second piece have a space.

What I want is a regex for following cases to split them in 2 pieces

```
apps; chrome
apps;chrome
```

I hope you understand, sorry for my english :)

Comment: Either `preg_split('/;\s*/', $search)` or just explode() them and trim() the resultant parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `trim` on the various parts.

e.g.

```
$parts =  array_map('trim', explode(';', $search));
```

Comment: Hmmm, trim function replace all spaces.. in case of "apps; google chrome" it will not work. THank you !

Comment: @DanielaRăducanu No, `trim()` replaces only whitespace on the ends of the string, not internally. this will work correctly.

Answer (score 3):

The [`trim`](http://php.net/trim) function will help:

```
list($k1,$k2) = array_map("trim",explode(";",$search));
```

One-liner! =3

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are sure about the separators, and you have two options, basically.

1) Using explode(';', $string) and array_map
This will explode the string and them apply trim() over the array;

```
$slices = explode(';', $string);
$slices_filtered = array_map("trim", $slices);
```

2) Using preg_split("/[,; \t\n]+/",$string);
This will split strings like "we  ,   are;  the \n champions" into {we,are,the,champions}

```
$slices_filtered = preg_split("/[,; \t\n]+/",$string);
```

** considering the 'options' won't have spaces on it; if they do, you should use some pattern like

```
/[,;][ ]*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Just because you'd specified a Regular Expression ... and this should allow you to match any 2 lower-case alpha strings separated by a semi-colon, with any number (or type) of whitespace "noise".

```
$sFullString = "app; chrome"; //or wherever you're getting your string from

//RegExp pattern to match many strings including "app;chrome"
$sRegExp = '/^\s*([a-z]+);\s*([a-z]+)\s*$/';

//first replacement
$sAppMatch = preg_replace($sRegExp, "$1", $sFullString);

//second replacement
$sChromeMatch = preg_replace($sRegExp, "$2", $sFillString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a trim() function before treating your $parts

Answer (score 0):

Why regex?

```
<?php
$parts = explode(";", $search);
foreach ($parts as $k => $v) {
  $parts[$k]=trim($v);
}
```

Comment: Because there might be more strings

Comment: And? Explode will match all of them assuming they are delimited with a `;`...Although I do like Kolink's answer better than mine, using array_map instead.